# Use two interpreters in a PyCharm project

Tags: python, pycharm, conda

I am using Pycharm 5.0.1.  I want to use two packages that exist in two envs.  Scipy is in a Conda env, and Tweepy is in the default env.

How can I use packages of both the interpreters in a single project?

Answer (score 2):

*If* both interpreters are the same major version of python--so that they share compatible byte code--you should be able to hack python's `sys.path` or the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to add the `site-packages` directory of one interpreter to the other.

I think.  Be careful.  This is incredibly hacky.

Best advice: Install tweepy for the scipy python interpreter.  Say `PYTHON` holds the location of the python interpreter for the conda env.  Then just `$PYTHON -m pip install tweepy`.

Also an option...  Use a channel from [anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/search?q=tweepy&sort=ndownloads&sort_order=1&reverse=true).  For example, if you're on Windows,  `conda install -c professoreaston tweepy`.

Comment: Hi kalefranz- Thanks for the help.. Your first advice, I didn't understand even a word, pls explain that to a novice like me. And just an update I was able to install tweepy by conda install -c professoreaston tweepy. But then, now I cant install pyprind by it, It seems I am in some trouble